# Does submit() on a form block?

Tags: javascript

I am running the following code which is:

```
iframedoc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

I need to execute code as soon as the form is done being submitted. Does the `submit()` block, or do I need some other way to determine when the form has been submitted?

Answer (score 2):

No, triggering a form submit does not block *or* return anything useful. It merely tells the browser to create a request which will render a new page. However, with an iframe the `onload` event can be used to handle the response from the form submit after it has loaded.

```
iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument;
iframe.onload = function(e) { 
    alert('frame loaded');
    // read its url, content, etc... 
};
iframedoc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
// immediately returns undefined and your code proceeds
```

Since JavaScript runs in a single thread, you won't see the 'frame loaded' alert until *all* of your subsequent code has completed, the browser submits the form, and the onload event triggers.